# Why doesn't nginx serve my static images?

Tags: nginx, uri

I have a bunch of static files like that:

```
/var/www/myroot/
                environment.js
                css/
                    vendor.css
                    main.css
                js/
                    main.js
                    vendor.js
                    app.js
```

nginx returns a 404 for every *.js or *.css file and I don't understand, why.

There is an application delivering a html index file which looks like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="/environment.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer" src="/js/vendors.js?v=9b77"></script>
    <script defer="defer" src="/js/main.js?v=9b77"></script>
    <script defer="defer" src="/js/app.js?v=9b77"></script>
    <link href="/css/vendors.css?v=9b77" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/main.css?v=9b77" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    ... some html code
</body>
</html>
```

Requests to / deliver this html code.
This is my nginx config file:

```
server { 
    # listen 443, certs etc.
    server_name my-domain.de;
    root /var/www/myroot/;
    
    location ~ ^\/$ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5002;
        # this delivers the html code shown above, so no more information about that
        ... more proxy statements
    }   
    
    # this block doesn't work as expected
    location ~* \.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)(\?.*|)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    
    # /whatever should deliver /
    # this seems to work
    location / {
        try_files $uri /;
    }
}
```

The urls to my .js and .css files have a query parameter which changes depending from the last write time of the file, so that the browser always fetches the newer version, if one exists.

nginx doesn't find the $uri with try_files $uri =404 and returns a 404 status code.

Could you share any insights which could help me getting further?

Thanks in advance.
-mm

Comment: Your server block should work, although the `(\?.*|)` bit is unnecessary as the query string is never considered by `location`. Check the access log and error log. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that the server block appears as described in your question.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did a complete system restart and after that the config worked. Maybe the problem came from too much experiments with nginx. An extra point for nginx -T ;-)